# Failed to create aks using existing vnet

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create aks using terraform; the catch is I have already vnet and subnet created, I need to have the cluster created in that network.

When executing this code I'm getting an error:

```
locals {
  environment     = "prod"
  resource_group =  "hnk_rg_poc"
  vnet_subnet_cidr = ["10.3.1.0/24"]
}

#Existing vnet with address space "10.3.1.0/24"
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing-vnet" {
  name                = "${var.vnet}"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
}

#subnets
resource "azurerm_subnet" "vnet_subnet_id" {
  name                 = "${var.vnet_subnet_id}"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group
  address_prefixes     = local.vnet_subnet_cidr
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing-vnet.name
}
```

```
vnet_subnet_id       =  data.azurerm_subnet.vnet_subnet_id.id
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already having a existing Vnet and Subnet to be used by the AKS cluster , you have to use data block instead of resource block for the subnet.

You can use the below to create a basic aks cluster using your existing Vnet and Subnet:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

#local vars

locals {
  environment     = "test"
  resource_group = "resource_group_name"
  name_prefix     = "name-aks"
}


#Existing vnet with address space 
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "base" {
  name                = "existing-vnet"
  resource_group_name = local.resource_group
}

#existing subnet to be used by aks

data "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
  name                 = "existing-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = local.resource_group
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.name
}


#kubernetes_cluster

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "base" {
  name                    = "${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"
  location                = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.location
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_virtual_network.base.resource_group_name
  dns_prefix              = "dns-${local.name_prefix}-${local.environment}"

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
  }


  default_node_pool {
    name           = "default"
    node_count     = 1
    vm_size        = "Standard_D2_v2"
    vnet_subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

**Output:** **(Terraform Plan)**

[image]